# Trying to convert Edit text to String, got error with "name".getText().toString() line

Tags: android, android-edittext, gettext

I am trying to use the new window and attaching edittext to get name from the user. It just always fail when it hits the line " "name"**.getText()**.toString()"

Here is my main

```
public class chatter extends Activity {

private String name;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.setNameMenu:
        setname();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void setname()
{
    final EditText textNameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameBox);
    /*Dialog dialog = new Dialog(chatter.this);
    dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
    */
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    //dialog.setCancelable(true);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitNameButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //String nameinput = textNameInput.getText().toString();
            **//this is where it does not work**
        **Editable debug1 = textNameInput.getText();**  
        String nameinput = debug1.toString();
            name = nameinput;
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is the layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialogueText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="please input your name:"
    />
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/nameBox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialogueText" />
<Button
    android:text=" Set "
    android:id="@+id/submitNameButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameBox"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am new to programing in android, please kindly explain what went wrong.

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "fail".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't posted a stacktrace I'm guessing at the error, but I'm thinking you are getting a `NullPointerException` as `textNameInput` is `null`.  You also haven't said which of the two layouts that you refer to in your code is the one that you have listed, but I'm guessing its `R.layout.custom_dialog`?  If so, then your call to `findViewById(R.id.nameBox)` will return `null` as it happens before you have loaded the layout that contains `R.id.nameBox`.  Move the call to after you load the layout.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `final EditText textNameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameBox);` before you have called `setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);`

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! I worked!!!! (I cannot check 2 people, sorry otherwise your answer is also same and correct!)